# Using multiple arrays as information in a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm struggeling a bit with arrays and user what's inside with loops. I have this question for example (ignore what's inside of the previewOrder method, i was trying stuff out):

```
public class Ex1_19 {
    final static String NAMES[]= {"Spa reine 25 ","Bru plate 50","Bru pét 50",
            "Pepsi","Spa orange", "Schweppes Tonic","Schweppes Agr","Ice Tea","Ice Tea Pêche",
            "Jus d'orange Looza", "Cécémel", "Red Bull","Petit Expresso","Grand Expresso","Café décaféiné ",
            "Lait Russe ","Thé et infusions","Irish Coffee ","French Coffee ","Cappuccino","Cécémel chaud",
            "Passione Italiano","Amour Intense", "Rhumba Caliente ","Irish Kisses ","Cuvée Trolls 25",
            "Cuvee Trolls 50","Ambrasse-Temps 25","Ambrasse-Temps 50 ","Brasse-Temps Cerises 25",
            "Brasse-Temps Cerises 50","La Blanche Ste Waudru 25","Blanche Ste Waudru 50",
            "Brasse-Temps citr 25","Brasse-Temps citr 50","Spaghetti Bolo ","Tagl Carbonara",
            "Penne poulet baslc ","Tagl American","Tagl saum"};
            
    final static double NETPRICES[]= {2.2, 2.3,3.9,2.2,2.2,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,4.5,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.5,2.5,7.0,7.0,2.8,2.8,6.2,6.2,6.2,6.2,
                                        2.9,5.5,2.7,5.1,3.1,5.8,2.6,4.9,2.6,4.9,10.8,11.2,12.2,14.5,16.9};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Order[][]={{3,2},{1,3},{12,4},{37,1},{36,3},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}, {0,0}};
        
        previewOrder(Order);
    }
    public static void previewOrder(int order[][]) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        
        while(i < order.length && j < order.length) {
            System.out.println(NAMES[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

My result has to be something like this but with what's inside the "order" array:

Bru pét 50 3.9 2 7,80
Spa reine 25 2.2 3 6,60
Red Bull 4.5 4 18,00
Tagl Carbonara 11.2 1 11,20
Spaghetti Bolo 10.8 3 32,40

In my exercice I have to use a while loop and I have to put the order array in my method parameters. I can't figure out how to make them all communicate.

Sorry if this question has been answered somewhere else but I don't know how to search for it.

**EDIT:** I know that Orders does not use zero based index, but starts at 1. This is probably because "Order" is supposed to be a user entry. The first number of the array is like a drink number.

I wasn't very clear on the expected output.
Bru pét 50 (NAME[3]) 3.9 (NETPRICE[3]) 2 (Order[][2]) 7.80 NETPRICE[3] * Order[][2] and this for every occurence in Order

Comment: From your example, I think I can guess what the program is supposed to do. But, I'm reluctant to rely on such guessing. Can you, please, edit your question to explain the example?

Comment: By the way, Java arrays are zero based. `"Bru pét 50"` would be `NAMES[2]`.

Comment: Possibly off-topic:  I don't like tightly coupled arrays. When I see that, I think of creating a `class`, e.g. `class Product { String name; double price; ...}`.

Comment: I edited the original post to explain the output a little better

Comment: May I suggest some edits? `NAMES` and `NETPRICES` are parallel arrays, with the former being names of products and the latter being corresponding unit price. That is, if `k` is an index, it is used to match a product with its price.  `Order` is an array of pairs: The first of a pair is the product number, the second of a pair is the quantity. /// Note that product number `n` is found by indexing the `NAMES` and `NETPRICES` by using `n - 1`.

Comment: (Continuing edit suggestion:) The `previewOrder` method is to print out one line for each order. The line should consist of the following: Product Name, Unit Price, Quantity, Total Amount.

Answer (score 0):

The `Order` array (btw: should be named *order* or *orders*) obviously contains references to ordered items and their amount. It's a two dimensional array, like a table with two columns.

Your expected output of "Bru pét 50 3.9 2 7,80", coming from Order[0] {3,2} indicates that the first element (Order[0][0]) is a reference to the items name (from `NAMES`) and the price (from `NETPRICES`). The second value of each "row" is the item amount (2) and finally there's the computed total.

For reasons unknown, Orders does not not use zero-based indexed, but starts at 1. So ORDER[0] having value {3,2} actually referes to NAMES[2] and NETPRICES[2]. This needs to be taken into account when picking the right item form NAMES and NETPRICES.

Anyhow: This is what your method could look like. You still need to tweak the output according to your needs.

```java
    public static void previewOrder(int order[][]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {

            int index = order[i][0] - 1;

            if (index < 0 || index > NAMES.length || index > NETPRICES.length) {
                continue;
            }

            String name = NAMES[order[i][0] - 1];
            double price = NETPRICES[order[i][0] - 1];
            int amount = order[i][1];
            double total = amount * price;

            System.out.println(
                    name + " " + price + " " + amount + " " + total
            );

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void previewOrder(int order[][]) {
    Stream.of(order)
        .filter(x -> x[0] != 0)
        .forEach(x -> {
            String name = NAMES[x[0] - 1];
            int unit = x[1];
            double price = NETPRICES[x[0] - 1];
            System.out.printf("%s %.1f %d %.2f%n",
            name, price, unit, price * unit);
        });
}
```

output:

```
Bru p?t 50 3.9 2 7.80
Spa reine 25  2.2 3 6.60
Red Bull 4.5 4 18.00
Tagl Carbonara 11.2 1 11.20
Spaghetti Bolo  10.8 3 32.40
```

or

```
public static void previewOrder(int order[][]) {
    for (int[] row : order) {
        if (row[0] == 0)
            continue;
        String name = NAMES[row[0] - 1];
        int unit = row[1];
        double price = NETPRICES[row[0] - 1];
        System.out.printf("%s %.1f %d %.2f%n",
            name, price, unit, price * unit);
    }
}
```

Comment: As this seems to work, I'm not very far in my course and only have seen the basics of programming. This particular exercise needs to be done with a simple while loop. I have no clue what your method is :p

Answer (score 0):

When I see tightly coupled arrays, I think of creating a class.

```
  public class Product {
      String name;
      double unitPrice;
      
      public Product () {
          name = "*** Unnamed Product ***";
          unitPrice = 0.0;
      }

      public Product (String name, double unitPrice) { 
          this.name = name;
          this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
      }

      public String getName () { return name; }
      public double getPrice () { return unitPrice; }
      public String toString () { return name + " @ " + unitPrice + " ea.";}
 }
```

Then, you can have one array where you previously had two:

```
public class Ex1_19 { 
     static final Product [] productList =  {
        new Product("Spa reine 25 ", 2.2),
        new Product("Bru plate 50", 2.3),
        new Product("Bru pét 50", 3.9),
        new Product("Pepsi", 2.2),
        new Product("Spa orange", 2.2),
        new Product("Schweppes Tonic", 2.6),
        new Product("Schweppes Agr", 2.6),
        new Product("Ice Tea", 2.6)
        // and so on 
     };      
}
```

The preview order method, without formatted output, might look like this:

```
public static void previewOrder (int[][] order) {
    double total = 0.0;
    double itemCount = 0;
    int lineNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < order.length; ++i) {
        int row = order[i][0] - 1;
        if (row < 0) { 
             break; 
        }
        int qty = order [i][1];
        double amt = productList [row].getPrice () * qty;
        System.out.println (++lineNum + "  " + productList[row].getName()
          + "  " +  productList[row].getPrice () + "  " +  qty
          + "  " + amt);
        itemCount += qty;
        total += amt;
    }
    System.out.println ("===\nTotal: " + total + "   for " + itemCount + " items.");
 }
```